# How to add comment box and post form to django rest framework

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, django

I created a site by following a django rest framework tutorial(http://192.241.153.25:8000)

and i finished hooking up login part and posts, 
but i have no clue in what way how i can put a posting form and comment box for the individual post.

here is what i have tried though

html

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" name="content" placeholder="content">
<button class="ladda-button button-primary login_button" ng-click="vm.submit()"/><span class="ladda-label">submit</span></button>
</form>
```

jquery

```
  $('#post_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: '/api/posts/create/',
    data:$('#post_form').serialize(),
    error: function(response){
      alert('Not authorized.');  // Or something in a message DIV
    },
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $('.login_bar').html(response)
      $('.login_bar').html(response)
      $('#logout_form').toggleClass(show)
    // do something with response
 }
});

});
```

and here is my API.

http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/posts/create/

could anyone help me out here?

Comment: here are my rest APIs

Comment: http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/posts/
http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/comments/
http://192.241.153.25:8000/api/comments/create/

Comment: How do your models and REST views look like?

Comment: @Azimkhan this is the post serializers.py https://dpaste.de/Epfa

Comment: and the views.py https://dpaste.de/Ddo1#L5

Answer (score 1):

Look at this exapmle:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[%s] %s" % (self.author, self.text)
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Post, Comment
from rest_framework import serializers


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text', 'author', 'post')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'comment_set')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .models import Post, Comment
from .serializers import CommentSerializer, PostSerializer


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()


class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import PostViewSet, CommentViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'posts', PostViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

**Sending a POST request in JSON format to `http://127.0.0.1/comments/` with the following content**:

```
{"author":"Jerry", "text": "Nice post!", "post": 1}
```

creates a new comment for post with id = 1 in this case

Comment: thanks for the example. but is there any way i can just put a comment without having to type in the 'post' number? for example, just like this stackoverflow comment system.

Comment: @MarkKang You could have nested resource design with the urls like `/posts/1/comments`. In this case you don't have to send post id cause id is determined in the url. But what's the problem with previous solution?

Comment: okay, but i already have create api for both post and comments. could you take a look at this page and why the post box doesn't work? http://192.241.153.25:8000/

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:
views.py :-

```
def adComment(request):
    print request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) #Validate your data with form. 
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.title = form.cleaned_data['username']
            instance.comments = form.cleaned_data['content']
            instance.save() #Will save your data if valid.
            data = {'success':True,'msg':"Store comment's data successfully"}
            return Response(data)

    else:
        data = {'success':False,'msg':'Error in storing comments'}
        return Response(data)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from models import commentData


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = commentData #Your model name created to store comment's data
        fields = [
                  "username", 
                  "content",

                  ]
```

Comment: sorry. but i am using plain DRF, which means there's no django template that renders what's inside the views.py. I use API.

Comment: You can use these function in urls with as_view().